# Why do I have gaming time in a game I haven't played

Tags: steam

I was going to return a game "Player Unknowns Battle Grounds" and when I checked the playtimes it says that I have played for 9 hours. I was confused because I only played it for 10 minutes until I realized my computer wasn't meeting the requirements for the game. That's why I wanted to return it. I still proceeded to return the game hoping they will still refund it. If not I will have to ask Steam support but if anyone can tell me how to fix it, that would be great.

Comment: Did you have the game running idle at a menu?

Comment: @Broneironaut: Do you have any reason to think that the number that steam support have will be any different to the one that steam is showing the OP? It would seem a bit strange if they didn't match (though knowing steam I wouldn't necessarily be surprised...)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, when a game does not meet the requirements of the system, it may freeze idle or minimised until you shut off your computer. It may have frozen and minimised instead of closing, which would cause an extra couple of hours on the steam timer. You may wanna contact steam support with your issue, and if they can't help you, you could always keep it for a later day when your computer is stronger.

Another thing is that in PUBG, even if your computer is terrible, you can try a few matches and get items, and win a small portion of your revenue back on the Community Market.

Comment: "Another thing is that in PUBG, even if your computer is terrible, you can try a few matches and get items, and win a small portion of your revenue back on the Community Market."  I definitely wouldn't try that unless you're sure steam wont refund you.  Also, OP may not be able to run the game at all; so it might not be possible.

Comment: @JMac he literally says up there 'played it for 10 mins' so he definitely can run it but at a terrible quality probably.

Comment: Depends on what he means by "played".  It's definitely possible he started the game; but couldn't do much beyond the lobby because the game is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Your playtime does not affect your chance of refunds.  It's really the repeated "abuse" of the system to try to play free games that will cause problems.

Steam refund details can be found [here](http://store.steampowered.com/steam_refunds/).

In fact, it specifically lists "hardware does not meet requirement" as one of the option for requesting a refund.

It also specifically says you can refund a recently purchased game and instantly re-purchase it at a sale price.

Comment: From the linked page: “Where refunds apply: The Steam refund offer, within two weeks of purchase and **with less than two hours of total playtime**”